# Docker internal private repository for publish and update?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry

I am just playing with Docker.  I have some scripts and Django web apps deployed internally.  I would like to publish these in docker containers to an internal private repo and have the deployed containers automatically update.

This is small scale and I am getting a bit lost down paths of AWS, Kubernetes, swarm, etc.  being so green I just want to start by being able to deploy and easily update containers completely internal to my organization.

My apologies if I am so new to docker that I am not asking the question the right way.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use continuous integration and continuous deployment model.

For example you can use Jenkins pipeline.

0 ) [Setup Private Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#copy-an-image-from-docker-hub-to-your-registry)

1 ) [Setup Jenkins server](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#installing-docker)

2 ) [Add Jenkinsfile to your project](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/)

3 ) [Use Jenkins Kubernetes Plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes)

After every commit your pipeline can built new docker image, push your private registry and publish your docker image to your kubernetes server.

Currently i am using this and works well on kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks!  Looking through it quickly and it sure seems like what I am after.  I will kick the tires and update.  Thanks for your help.